# How can I use a function to create a persistant list correlated to the given arguments?

Tags: python, function

I'm writing a script to find the moving average of different stocks. This script runs continuously, looping through my API call to add the current price to a list before averaging it. This works fine, however I'd like to be able to put this into a function to where the only input I need to give it is the name of the stock. I'd like this script to work for as many stocks as I want to specify, at the same time. That's where I run into issues because for each stock I have I need to have an empty list predefined that can hold the pricing information.

I've been trying to use the name of the stock to then create a related list, but as I now understand it it's not a great idea using one variable name to create another variable, so I'm not sure what to do. I believe the usual solution here would be to use a dictionary, but I'm a beginner to programming in general so I haven't figured out how to fit that into my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def sma(stock_name):
    list_exists = stock_name + "_list" in locals() or stock_name + "_list" in globals()
    if list_exists:  
        print()
    else:
        stock_name + "_list" = []  # Problem line, I would like for this to create a list called stock_name_list
    stock_price = requests.get("myapi.com", params={"stock_name": stock_name, "bla bla": "blah"}) 
    stock_name_list.append(stock_price)
```

Comment: You've identified the central problem: you do not **yet** know enough programming to cleanly solve this problem.  Work through tutorials on dictionary and class.

Comment: @Prune. When you put it like that, I have to join in with my close vote. Not going to remove my answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an operation based on a version of the data specific to that operation, that is usually a good time to think about using classes. This particular proposed class will encapsulate the name of a stock, the list of data specific to it, and perform `sma` on it:

```
class Stock:
    n = 10

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = []

    def sma(self):
        stock_price = requests.get("myapi.com", params={"stock_name": self.stock_name, "bla bla": "blah"}) 
        self.data.append(stock_price)
        window = self.data[-n:]
        return sum(window) / len(window)
```

Now you can maintain a dictionary of these objects. Any time you encounter a new stock, you just add an item to the dictionary:

```
stocks = {}

def sma(name):
    stock = stocks.get(name)
    if name is None:   # None is what get returns when the key is missing
        stock = Stock(name)
        stocks[name] = stock
    return stock.sma()
```

The nice thing is that you now have a dictionary of named datasets. If you want to add a different statistic, just add a method to the `Stock` class that implements it.

I defined a global `sma` function here that calls the eponymous method on the object it finds in your dictionary. You can carry encapsulation to an exterme by making the method perform the action of the function if called statically with a name instead of an instance. For example:

```
class Stock:
    n = 10
    named_stocks = {}  # This is a class variable that replaces the global stocks

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data = []

    def sma(self):
        if isinstance(self, str):
            self = Stock.get_stock(self)
        stock_price = requests.get("myapi.com", params={"stock_name": self.stock_name, "bla bla": "blah"}) 
        self.data.append(stock_price)
        window = self.data[-n:]
        return sum(window) / len(window)

    @classmethod
    def get_stock(cls, name):
        stock = cls.named_stocks.get(name)
        if stock is None:
            stock = cls(name)
            cls.named_stocks[name] = stock
        return stock
```

Now that there is a check for `isinstance(self, str)`, you can call the `sma` method in one of two ways. You can all it directly on an instance, which knows its own name:

```
aapl = Stock('AAPL')
aapl.sma()
```

OR

```
Stock.get_stock('AAPL').sma()
```

Alternatively, you can call it on the class, and pass in a name:

```
Stock.sma('AAPL')
```

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth answer, I got everything working with a class and I feel I understand it fairly well.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you were able to use it. This is really a good textbook example of when oop makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

stock_name_to_stock_prices = defaultdict(list)
stock_name_to_stock_prices['STOCK_NAME'].append(123.45)
```